# Can this JavaScript singleton be improved?

Tags: javascript, singleton

I needed a singleton in JavaScript in order to make a DataManager which is called multiple times, but I just want it to load its data only the first time it is called, then give pieces of the data out view public methods, never loading the initial data again.

I found a number of approaches to building singletons in JavaScript but this one seems to have everything I need.

Does anyone see any kind of problem this singleton is going to have for the uses I need it for?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test singleton</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var DatapodManager = (function() {
                var instantiated;
                that = this;

                //DEFINE INTERNAL VARIABLES HERE:
                var message = '';

                function init() {

                    //LOAD DATA ONCE HERE:
                    that.message = 'singleton message defined at: ' + getMilliseconds();


                    //ALLOW PUBLIC ACCESS TO SINGLETON DATA HERE:
                    return {
                        getMessage : function() {
                            return that.message;
                        },
                        id : '1234'
                    }
                }

                return {
                    getInstance : function() {
                        if(!instantiated) {
                            instantiated = init();
                        }
                        return instantiated;
                    }
                }
            })()

            function dowait() {
                for( x = 1; x <= 10000000; x++) {
                    var y = 1000;
                    var z = 2000;
                    var b = y * z;
                }
            }

            function getMilliseconds() {
                var d = new Date();
                return d.getMilliseconds();
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                console.log('getting first singleton message at: '+getMilliseconds());
                console.log(DatapodManager.getInstance().getMessage());
                dowait();
                console.log('getting second singleton message at: '+getMilliseconds());
                console.log(DatapodManager.getInstance().getMessage());
                console.log('the static id is '+DatapodManager.getInstance().id);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
```

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: Is that java factory?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use an object literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Once you start to chain properties or function calls, you incur performance penalty due to scope differences. It's best you keep the property/function depth to a minimum. This ain't Java or AS3 that needs deep namespacing.
- What's the idea of `getInstance()`? Can't the singleton module itself be the instance?
- Regarding the output image, it is correct. You get the first message at 440ms, then the singleton created the message at 442ms during `init()`. The next call you made is at 482ms. Since the instance was already created, the same message (the one created at 442ms) was used.

Here's [a very short version](http://jsfiddle.net/qCFPH/) of it. Basically, I just removed `getInstance()` and made `DatapodManager` the instance. No visible speed difference but you have shorter code. I also preserved the idea of it being a closure in case you ever needed private properties:

```
var DatapodManager = (function () {
    return {
        message: 'singleton message defined at: ' + getMilliseconds(),
        getMessage: function () {
            return this.message
        },
        id: '1234'
    }
}());
```